# Initial pose for robot_localization within a given map

Tags: navigation, mapping, robot-localization, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am able to run r_l package fuing wheel odometry, imu and gps. Now I want to run the localization within a predefined map.

As briefly mentioned [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/288429/how-to-set-up-robot_localization-with-gmapping-imu-and-gps/), I have to initialize a robot pose within a map before calling navsat_tranform.

I don't know how to do it. Let's say the robot starts within a map with an arbitrary pose, I wonder is there any way to set that pose before calling navsat_transform?

For example, my current localization result within a prior looks like this:
[image: image description]

The blue arrows are fused odometry using wheel encoder, imu and gps. The localization result in world_frame is satisfying.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298337/initial-pose-for-robot_localization-within-a-given-map/) by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2018-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The initial pose has it's  own topic. You can publish to this topic from a node. RVIZ publishes to this topic when you set initial pose using the mouse.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-07-24**:
@billy yes you are right. But setting the pose using rviz only effects the initial pose of amcl right? Since robot localization package didn't subscribe to any initial pose topic then how can you set an initial pose for it? Or maybe I miss something?

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-07-24**:
Ah yes, I found it. [Initial state](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#initial-state) can be called to set the initial pose. Thank you for your help!

**Comment by [hwlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/50917/hwlee/) on 2020-03-03**:
Great!! I had same problem and you had solved it. Thanks :)